Servo motors for turning a mixing valve
I am working on a project for my mechanical engineering degree involving temperature controlled showers. I was wondering what specific servo motor I would need to turn a thermostatic mixing valve. At the moment I have researched the TowerPro SG-5010, I see that it turns 180 degrees and I think it is sufficient for what I need it to do. Any advice on whether this is good enough or if there are other would be appreciated

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
